# Prove $\prod\limits_{n=1}^\infty (1 + a_n)$ converges if and only if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, infinite-product

Prove $\displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1 + a_n)$ converges if and only if $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges.

*Note: There are proofs of this readily available.  My question is to point me in the direction for myself to prove it.  Please do* not *finish my proof.  Instead, please tell me if I'm going in the right direction or, if not, provide gentle assistance.*

I'm having trouble completing this proof, and would like help taking the next step.  Please do *not* give away the full proof.  Below are my approaches.

Given $(a_n)$, let $s_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ and $p_n = \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1 + a_n)$.  To simplify, I will first suppose $a_n \geq 0$ for all $n$.

**Approach 1:**

Suppose $(s_n)$ converges.  For any $a > 0$, there exists a $k$ such that $a_n < a$.  Then, $p_n \leq p_k(1 + a)^{n-k}$ for $n \geq k$.  Can we show $\lim_{n \to \infty}(1 + a)^{n-k}$ converges?

I tried applying the binomial theorem, or taking the log, neither of which simplified this.

I imagined taking a continuous extension, giving the indeterminate form $(1 + 0)^\infty$, so I could apply L'Hopital's rule, but made no progress.

**Approach 2:** Replace the infinite product with an infinite sum of $\log (1 + a_n)$ and show this converges.  No progress here either.

**Approach 3:** $p_{n+1} = p_n + p_n a_n$.  I tried to use this to form a sequence or series that I could show converges.

**Approach 4:** $p_{n+1} = p_n(1 + a_n)$. If I knew $(p_n)$ was bounded, I believe I could use this to show convergence.  But I could not prove $(p_n)$ was bounded.

Comment: First, get the definitions of $s_n$ and $p_n$ correct (Hint: use subscript $k$ on the right). Approach 2 is the right way to go.

Comment: Can you explain where you're having trouble with Approach $2$? Maybe there's something I'm missing, but it seems fairly straightforward...

Comment: @TedShifrin @ BrianTung Got it! For all $a > 0, \log(1+a) < a,$ thus by the Squeeze Theorem, $(p_n)$ converges! Now on to prove the converse.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product

Comment: @SRobertJames The title, and the first line of your question, are incomplete.  You mean "... if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ *converges*", right?

Comment: The stated proposition is false in general. It is true if either $a_n\geq0$ for all $n$ or $a_n\leq0$ for all $n.$ See the Wikipedia article referred to by @GEdgar, or for more detail, Chapter 5 of Peter Duren, *Invitation to Classical Analysis* (2012).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Look at $$
\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\log(1+x)}{x}
$$

---

Your four approaches are all very reasonable. It just takes some tinkering to find out which one will ultimately get you the right answer. I think approach 3 could be used to prove that convergence of the product implies convergence of the sum, but the other direction would be tough. However, you should be able to get both directions from approach 2.

Comment: Thank you.  This clarified approach 2 for one direction, and I'm working on the converse.  I'm glad that my other approaches are reasonable as well - I had the feeling that I was grasping at straws.  For my education, can you flesh out a bit how you'd take the other approaches?

Comment: 1 and 4 I don't see going anywhere.

Comment: @SRobertJames being able to come up with an approach is as important as finding the right one. So if you find yourself grasping with straws, at least you're grasping at something.