# Are there any abundant numbers that is not divisible by $3$ and is form of $55\dots5$?

Tags: number-theory

Are there any abundant numbers that is not divisible by $3$ and is form of $5\underbrace{5..5}_{n \text { times}}5$
?

Given that the number of $5$'s is not divisible by $3$, I think $55\dots5$ can be an odd abundant number, since there is an odd abundant number that is not divisible by $3$.

Using Pari GP, I checked the values of $n\leq100$, but none of the numbers listed there is an odd abundant number.

Comment: No, take $n=5s=5555$ with $s=555$, which is divisible by $3$. Or do you mean $5\cdot s$?

Comment: All your questions look the same.  Have you tried anything?  The first step is generally a search.  But, of course, the first odd abundant number prime to $3$ has ten digits, so you are looking at a pretty sparse set.

Comment: If there is an abundant number that is the product of primes $p\equiv 5 \pmod 6$, then you can find a number of the form $555...55$ that is not divisible by $3$ but which is divisible by that abundant number making it abundant itself.

Comment: To reiterate what **Jaap Scherphuis** just said: yes there are such numbers, and we can easily find some of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are infinitely many such numbers.

*Proof* :

Jaap Scherphuis's comment is helpful.

Let $p_i$ be the $i$-th prime of the form $6m+5$ larger than $5$. $(p_1=11,p_2=17,p_3=23,\cdots)$

Then, let us consider an abundant number of the form $\displaystyle N=\prod_{i=1}^{n}p_i$.

There are infinitely many such $N$.

(The reason is as follows : Since $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac 1{p_i}$ diverges (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions)), it follows from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4563786/prove-prod-limits-n-1-infty-1-a-n-converges-if-and-only-if-sum-limit) that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sigma(N)}{N}=\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\bigg(1+\frac{1}{p_i}\bigg)$ diverges.)

Since $\gcd(N,10)=1$, we have, by Euler's theorem,
$$10^{\varphi(N)}\equiv 1\pmod N$$
where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function.

Since $\gcd(N,9)=1$, there is a positive integer $k$ such that
$$\frac{10^{\varphi(N)}-1}{9}=kN\tag1$$

Here, $\dfrac{10^{\varphi(N)}-1}{9}$ is not divisible by $3$ since
$$\begin{align}\frac{10^{\varphi(N)}-1}{9}&=10^{\varphi(N)-1}+10^{\varphi(N)-2}+\cdots+10+1
\\\\&\equiv \varphi(N)\pmod 3
\\\\&\equiv\prod_{i=1}^{n}(p_i-1)\pmod 3
\\\\&\equiv \prod_{i=1}^{n}1\pmod 3
\\\\&\equiv 1\pmod 3\end{align}$$

From $(1)$, there are positive integers $k',N'$ such that $\gcd(k',N')=1,\text{rad}(N)=\text{rad}(N')$ and
$$\frac{10^{\varphi(N)}-1}{9}=k'N'$$
where $\text{rad}(t)$ is the product of the distinct prime factors of $t$.

So, we can write $N'=\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{n}p_i^{a_i}$ where $a_i\ge 1$.

Now, $\sigma(N')\gt 2N'$ holds since
$$\frac{\sigma(N')}{N'}=\prod_{i=1}^n\bigg(1+\frac{1}{p_i}+\cdots +\frac{1}{p^{a_i}}\bigg)\ge\prod_{i=1}^n\bigg(1+\frac{1}{p_i}\bigg)=\frac{\sigma(N)}{N}\gt 2$$

So, $5k'N'$ is an abundant number since
$$\sigma(5k'N')=\sigma(5)\sigma(k')\sigma(N')\gt 6\sigma(k')\cdot 2N'\ge 12k'N'\gt 2\cdot 5k'N'$$

Therefore, $\dfrac{5(10^{\varphi(N)}-1)}{9}$ is an abundant number which is not divisible by $3$.$\ \blacksquare$